# Trouble with header files & c++ files

Tags: c++, static-libraries, header-files

I'm creating a minimal circle-circle physics engine in a static library, and I've came across a problem.  I have a header file for object manipulation, one of the variables is the objects position.  The position variable is declared in bpObject.h, and I have a void function, SetPosition(), that accesses the current position and sets its to the parameters specified (also declared in bpObject.h).  My problem is that in the source file, I need to access the position variable (private).  I can't access it through the bpObject class, because, being a class, it won't have the correct value when it is used as a type.  So, how would I access the position variable within the class?

Thanks in advance,

Greg Treleaven

### EDIT

Code for bpObject.h

```
#include "bpMath.h"

namespace bp
{
    class Object
    {
    private:
    static bp::Vector position;
    static bp::Vector velocity;
    static bp::Vector acceleration;
    public:
    static single restitution;
    static single radius;
    static void setPosition(single X, single Y);
    static bp::Vector getPosition();
    static void applyPosition(single X, single Y);
    static void setVelocity(single X, single Y);
    static bp::Vector getVelocity();
    static void applyVelocity(single X, single Y);
    static void setAcceleration(single X, single Y);
    static bp::Vector getAcceleration();
    static void applyAcceleration(single X, single Y);
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to add actual (minimal) code that represents your problem.

Comment: Why not add a member to `bpObject` class to get back the current position?

Comment: If the Object class has the position as a member variable and the SetPosition function is also a member of the Object class, then you should have no problem manipulating the position. Show some code so that we can see what you are actually having problems with.

Comment: "...being a class, it won't have the position variable contained when it is used as a type." If you mean that the variable won't have the correct *value* at the time that it's needed, then you have a more serious design problem than you realize. If you mean it literally, then I suspect you just don't know how classes work.

Comment: @Beta: I did mean the former, yes.

Comment: is it on purpose that all methods and members of `Object` are static ? This resembles more the functionality of a namespace rather than a class (e.g. you can only have one `position` in your entire program etc.)

Comment: Why do you have so many things declared `static`?  Why even bother to have a class if everything is going to be a `static`?  Why not just have a namespace?  I too suspect you misunderstand how classes work and what they're for.

Comment: @Omnifarious: You'll give me a lecture about how classes work and what they are for? The tutorial I followed to get me started had static for everything, i've taken them out now as i've seen they cause problems.

Comment: @Greg:  My suggestion about the tutorial you used:  find something else, and post where you got the tutorial so we can warn other people against it.  There's an excellent book list at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list, and free books, some of them for C++, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books.  Anything on there is likely to be better than what you're using now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't actually want all those 'static's in there, is your first problem (as it stands, you pretty much can only access a single object)

Once you get rid of those, you can implement SetPosition in your source file by:

```
namespace bp {
    void Object::SetPosition(single X, single Y) {
        position[0] = X; //or however your bp::Vector is implemented
        position[1] = Y;
    }
}
```

Yes, position is private, but when you actually define the method, you get to access the members. Is this at all what you are asking?

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was asking. 1-up, and tick!

Answer (score 0):

You're asking *the wrong question*. If, as you say, the variable doesn't have the correct value when it's needed, then the problem has nothing to do with access methods or public/private.

How is the variable supposed to get its proper value? Something must call `setPosition`, so you have to arrange things so that this happens *before* anything else needs that value.

Once you have that, your accessors (`setPosition` and `getPosition`) should work just fine (after you get rid of the `static`, which makes no sense).